# Infopath 2010 > Submitting to a SP List

Tags: infopath

Found this good link. The title says Infopath 2010 but publishing date and url is 2007. I thought steps for 2010 would be much easier than 2007 as I heard 2010 has improvements. Can anyone please confirm this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/03/26/submitting-to-a-sharepoint-list.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments

Thanks
Robin Li

Comment: Did you try it and it didn't work? What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to follow it. Though it is enough to follow much simpler original article:

- Matt Faus [Add SharePoint List Items with InfoPath](http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/matt/archive/2006/02/02/Add-SharePoint-List-Items-with-InfoPath.aspx)

I am using Infopath 2010 publishing to Sharepoint Online (Office 365) publishing from Windows XP SP3 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The steps are almost same for InfoPath2010 and InfoPath2007.